# How to search by computed field in odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I can't search by computed field

I override the name field in product.template to be computed so I need to search by name about the product

```
class autopart(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
@api.depends('item', 'car', 'model', 'dsc', 'drc', 'year', 'org')
def compute_amount(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.name = " ".join(
            [rec.item and rec.item.name or "", rec.car and rec.car.name or "", rec.model and rec.model.name or "",
             rec.dsc and rec.dsc.name or "", rec.drc and rec.drc.name or "", rec.org and rec.org.name or "",
             rec.year and rec.year.name or ""])
def pro_search(self, operator, value):
    if operator == 'like':
        operator = 'ilike'
        print('I'am In')
    return [('name', operator, value)]

name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=False ,compute=compute_amount,search=pro_search)
```

Comment: Add the attribute `store = True` in field definition.

Comment: if i add store = True the field will be empty and will not change when i change the items in Master data

Comment: `@api.multi` and `required=False` are not needed and you have an `unescaped quote`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, compute field does not store in the database, it `store=False`. If you want to search, then you have to store that value in your database, so just set `store=True`.

```
name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=False ,compute=compute_amount,search=pro_search, store=True)
```

Comment: if i added store = True  name not change when master data changes 
also just i add store = True name gone to be False

Answer (score 0):

Computed fields cannot be searched by default, because there's no database value for them.

If the result of your computed field always depends on a combination of other fields, you can use the `@api.depends()` decorator on the computed method and set the field as `store=True`. This is the easiest way to do it.

However, on some circumstances it just isn't enough because the computed field result depends on more things (i.e. the context (date, lang, etc.)). In such case, you have to add a search method as you are doing above in your question.

However, the main problem in your code is that the returned domain is, again, based on the `name` field in this part of the code:

```
return [('name', operator, value)]

name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=False ,compute=compute_amount,search=pro_search)
```

This is wrong. The `name` field is computed, you cannot search on it. You have to translate this domain into one that only searches on stored fields.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already stated, you need to add `store=True` in the field declaration. However, if you are doing this on an existing database, all the records will have the default value or be empty. This is because th ORM is just adding a new column in the psql table but no inserting the values.

You need to manually call compute_amount on all your records in order to populate the database.

Note that you are never supposed to change the fields declaration for use with an existing database if you want to be sure not to have problems.